# Representing Functions as Power Series

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, power-series

Rewrite $$f(x)=(1+x)/(1-x)^2$$ as a power series.

**Work thus far:**

I separated it into two parts:

$$1/(1-x)^2 + x/(1-x)^2$$

I realize that the first expression is the derivative of $1/(1-x)$ and come up with this sum of series:

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n$$

Since a derivative was involved, we must derive the series:

$$\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^\infty nx^{n-1} + x \displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^\infty nx^{n-1}$$
$$=\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^\infty nx^{n-1} + \displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^\infty nx^n$$

These series need to be added, but how?

The final answer is $\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^\infty (2n+1)x^n$

Comment: +$1$ for showing work/effort in your homework. Thanks

Comment: @EngGenie : Is there a reason why you put "plus" sigs OUTSIDE of the TeX environment?  That causes their size to fail to match that of the surrounding notation and sometime causes bad spacing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Shift the indices so that the powers of $n$ inside match:

$$\begin{align*}
\sum_{n\ge 0}nx^{n-1}+\sum_{n\ge 0}nx^n&=\sum_{n\ge 1}nx^{n-1}+\sum_{n\ge 0}nx^n\\\\
&=\sum_{n\ge 0}(n+1)x^n+\sum_{n\ge 0}nx^n\\\\
&=\sum_{n\ge 0}(2n+1)x^n\;.
\end{align*}$$

It may be easier to understand at first if you write out a few terms:

$$\left(1+2x+3x^2+\ldots+(n+1)x^n+\ldots\right)+\left(x+2x^2+3x^3+\ldots+nx^n+\ldots\right)$$

Here you can see that the coefficient of $x^n$ in the first sum is $n+1$, and the coefficient of $x^n$ in the second sum is $n$, so when you combine the sums the coefficient of $x^n$ must be $2n+1$.

If you find the shift

$$\sum_{n\ge 1}nx^{n-1}=\sum_{n\ge 0}(n+1)x^n$$

a bit mysterious, do it with an intermediate step: let $k=n-1$, so that $n=k+1$, and substitute to get

$$\sum_{n\ge 1}nx^{n-1}=\sum_{k+1\ge 1}(k+1)x^k=\sum_{k\ge 0}(k+1)x^k\;,$$

and then just rename the index variable back to $n$.

Comment: Great answer, thanks! One question though: In your first line you indexed your first summation to start at n=0, then switched it to n=1. What allowed you to change the starting position from 0 to 1 without changing anything else?

Comment: @EngGenie: The $n=0$ term of that sum has a coefficient of $0$, so it can be dropped: it’s $0$.

Comment: Ah, of course. Thanks again!

Comment: @EngGenie: You’re welcome!

Answer (score 0):

Expand $(1-x)^2$ into $(1-2x+x^2)$.

Then use long division to divide $(1-2x+x^2)$ into $(1+x)$.

Stop when you have enough terms in the quotient to identify the pattern.

Seems too easy??

Answer (score 0):

$$
\frac{1}{1-x}=1+x+x^2+x^3+\ldots
$$
$$
\frac{1}{(1-x)^2}=1+2x+3x^2+4x^3+\ldots
$$
$$
\frac{1+x}{(1-x)^2}=1+2x+3x^2+\ldots +x+2x^2+ 3x^3+\ldots=1+3x+5x^2+7x^3+\ldots
$$